# separate you from VS keep you from

Tags: vocabulary

For context: the participant who is on the 1st place now has earned 10 points, and the participant on the 2nd place has earned 5 points. How can I say that 5 points separate the second place from the first?
Like in the sentence: "5 points separate/keep you from the 1st place."

Comment: "Keep" does not sound idiomatic to me. "There are [now/only] 5 points separating you and 1st place." __ "There are [now/only] 5 points between you and 1st place."__

Comment: *… who is **in** (1st / 2nd) place …*

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I would say, "The contender in first place has a five point **lead**."